# Why is it possible to backup the rom images from mediatek devices using third party (open source) tools such as SP flash tool unlike Google Pixel?

Tags: kernel, android

When running Linux i am able to use SP flash tool to do a readback from my mediatek device and do a full backup of the rom images while the device is in preloader mode, without the use of any additional USB drivers.

Yet this is not possible with Google Pixel.

Is this perhaps due to Mediatek going out of their way and adding support for their devices during the development of the mainline linux kernel and Google dont?

Comment: Guess: It's possible because Mediatek **was not** going out of their way to make it hidden, and some clever developer figured out how to do it, and wrote the drivers. I've never seen any company that goes out of their way to support Linux when it comes to using flash.

Comment: sp flash tool doesnt need any drivers though, it just reads it straight away

Comment: Reads from where? :-) There's a whole stack of drivers involved in this, even if you don't see them.

Comment: sp flash tool reads the partition information on the emmc from the device straight away, whereas for windows we need to find and install mediatek VCOM drivers from third party sources

Comment: And how does it read the emmc "from the device straight away"? Can you name the kernel drivers that are involved in this?

Comment: Im saying when the mediatek device is in preloader mode (which allows flashing to a bricked device while it is turned off), windows requires third party vcom drivers for sp flash tool to work with the device, but why doesnt linux need these third party drivers as well?

Comment: Cross posting: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/228791/218526

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the kernel drivers, [this here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/mmc/host/mtk-sd.c) seems to be the Mediatek driver, and it says

```
* Copyright (c) 2014-2015 MediaTek Inc.
* Author: Chaotian.Jing <chaotian.jing@mediatek.com>
```

so it looks like at least originally this was contributed by Mediatek. Though it's also possible someone took Mediatek code and massaged it into a Linux kernel driver, but one would have to check the repository history for that.

And this driver does not live in isolation, as I said, there's the whole MMC driver stack involved.